# Accessing Video.js player without ID

Tags: jquery, video.js

I have some `<video>` tags without ID on my page. I have to access them to set up some features. I've tried to use jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('video').each(function(){ $(this)[0].player.play() }
});
```

but it seems that at this point videojs isn't initialized.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function() { } );`?

Comment: I've wrapped it in a `$(function(){})` - jQuery ready function

Comment: try using `$(this).get(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a video element as the argument to `videojs()` to create the player

```
$(function(){
  $('video').each(function(){
    videojs($(this)[0]).play();
  });
});
```